# How to get ObjectID from ArcGIS FeatureLayer on click function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to work with ArcGIS JavaScript API. I'm using [this FeatureLayer example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-popupTemplate/index.html) and I try to make a popup, which will display different data based on the objectID I click on. Basically what you see on that example.

The problem is that I can't actually access the ObjectID outside variable template. Inside this variable template you just set title like title: "ID of this object is {ObjectID}". That works good. But I have my data stored in my MySQL database so I want to get the ObjectID stored into variable when I click it and then possibly send it through ajax to some route. Then in controller find matched object, get its data from database and send it back to the popup template and display it.

That's my idea how it could possibly work, but I need to get the ObjectID first, which I don't know how to access. If you have any idea how it could be solved or you know a better way how to put additional data from database into the PopupTemplate, let me know please. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, On) {
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/NYCDemographics1/FeatureServer/0",
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "streets",
            layers: [featureLayer]
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            zoom: 11,
            center: [-73.950, 40.702] //CZ [16, 49]
        });

        var template = {
            title: "Marriage in NY, Zip Code: {ZIP}",
            content: "<p>As of 2015, <b>{MARRIEDRATE}%</b> of the population in this zip code is married.</p>" +
            "<ul><li>{MARRIED_CY} people are married</li>" +
            "<li>{NEVMARR_CY} have never married</li>" +
            "<li>{DIVORCD_CY} are divorced</li><ul>"
        };

        featureLayer.popupTemplate = template;

        On(featureLayer, 'click', function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Can you post the JS code for just your popup template? And to clarify: you are asking how to have the popup say `ID of this object is 1`, `ID of this object is 2`, etc.?

Comment: @Erica I use basically what's in the example, just check it. No, that's what is easy to make and works well, because the ObjectID is directly stored in the layer on ArcGIS server if I got it right. So in template you just use the syntax {ObjectID} or {ATTRIBUTE_NAME} or whatever and the popup is rendered with the actual values. What I want is to show additional data from my local database in the popup, not the ones that are stored on ArcGIS server. I have a database of invasive plants and I store image links, descriptions, names of them etc and I want these data to show in the popup aswell.

Comment: When you click the FeatureLayer, the click event will return an object called "object", but really is a esri.Graphic object, which is basically a feature. You can access the feature attributes in that object, including the ObjectID.

Answer (score 1):

with `"dojo/on"` you can handle the click event on your feature layer, then get attributes of the shape you clicked on :

```
On(featureLayer, 'click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.graphic.attributes.OBJECTID);
});
```

Comment: That looks good, I was looking for something like this, but it doesn't work at all. No console log when I click on featureLayer, even though the template pops up. I updated my question with my actual code, so you can check it. I'm using version ArcGIS for JavaScript version 4 by the way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There will be something with the featureLayer. I tried 
view.on('click', function(e){
                console.log(e);
});
and works fine, but I need the OBJECTID from featureLayer, but it doesn't work with it.

Comment: Ok, I have it! https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=view-hittest It works a little bit different, it doesn't ask the FeatureLayer itself, but it asks the view to get the screenPoint(x, y) and the view returns response with graphics and attributes of feature layers and so on that lies on the particular screenPoint co I can get these attributes which you pointed at. Thank for your help once again. @user1851595

Comment: it's greet to see you've resolve your problem. i'm glad if we have helped you a way or another